# Better way than two for loops (nested) in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have two dict and want to map the values, if both the keys mapped then print yes, please note here keys can be more than two so want dynamically. [if a key is added in keys dict then a value will also be added for that in dict a.]

```
a = {
  'value1': 1,
  'value2': 2
}

b = {
  'keys': {
    'key1': 'value1',
    'key2': 'value2'
  },
  'mapping': [{
      'check': {
        'key1': 3,
        'key2': 4
      }
    },
    {
      'check': {
        'key1': 5,
        'key2': 6
      }
    },
    {
      'check': {
        'key1': 1,
        'key2': 2
      }
    }
  ]
}

for i in b['mapping']:
  flag = True
for key, value in b['keys'].items():

  if not a.get(value) == i['check'][key]:
  flag = False
break

if flag:
  print('yes')
break
```

Here you can see that keys values are actually the keys of "dict a".

Written the above code but is there a better way to do that in python.

Comment: Do you want to just print 'yes' if you found a match, or do you need to print any more info about where you found the match?

Comment: If it matches a condition with both the keys, then it just print yes and then break out from the loop. [basically ends both loop as soon as it matches both the keys condition]

Answer (score 1):

Generally, if you have a loop where you set or clear a flag and then break based on a condition, you can replace it with `any` or `all`.

In this case,

```
flag = True
for key, value in b['keys'].items():
    if not a.get(value) == i['check'][key]:
        flag = False
        break
```

can be replaced by

```
flag = all(a.get(value) == i['check'][key] for key, value in b['keys'].items())
```

Comment: here how are you iterating over check as i['check'][key] is also inside a list.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the values are hashable (e.g., `int` as shown), you can turn them into sets for the comparison.

```
wanted = set((b_key, a[b_value]) for b_key, b_value in b["keys"].items())

for check_dict in b['mapping']:
    check = set(check_dict['check'].items())
    if wanted.issubset(check):
        print("yes")
        break
```

With a nod to mkrieger1, you could compress that to

```
wanted = set((b_key, a[b_value]) for b_key, b_value in b["keys"].items())
if any(wanted.issubset(set(check_dict['check'].items()))
        for check_dict in b['mapping']):
    print("yes")
```